# Adding missing dates and locations to data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, data-generation

I am new to SQL, it would be great if you help me. my SQL output is:

```
| o_date |  c_loc | type | output|\
|3-1-22  |  center 1   |   A     |   52  |\
|3-1-22  |  center 1   |   B     |   23  |\
|3-1-22  |  center 1   |   C     |   19  |\
|3-1-22  |  center 2   |   A     |   34  |\
|3-1-22  |  center 2   |   B     |   21  |\
|3-1-22  |  center 3   |   A     |   59  |\
|3-2-22  |  center 1   |   A     |   45  |\
|3-2-22  |  center 1   |   B     |   29  |
```

As you can see, there are some dates that some locations had no output. I need to fill this lines with 0. There are 11 centers with 3 types. What I need is the table below:

```
| o_date |  c_loc | type | output|\
|3-1-22  |  center 1   |   A     |   52  |\
|3-1-22  |  center 1   |   B     |   23  |\
|3-1-22  |  center 1   |   C     |   19  |\
|3-1-22  |  center 2   |   A     |   34  |\
|3-1-22  |  center 2   |   B     |   21  |\
|3-1-22  |  center 2   |   C     |   0   |\
|3-1-22  |  center 3   |   A     |   59  |\
|3-1-22  |  center 3   |   B     |   0   |\
|3-1-22  |  center 3   |   C     |   0   |\
|3-2-22  |  center 1   |   A     |   45  |\
|3-2-22  |  center 1   |   B     |   29  |\
|3-2-22  |  center 1   |   C     |   0   |
```

and etc.

As far as I understood I need to use { generate_series()}.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

No, your requirement does not need `generate_series`, which is not supported by MySql.

You need a `CROSS` join of the distinct combinations of `o_date` and `c_loc` to the distinct `type`s and a `LEFT` join to the table:

```
SELECT t1.o_date, t1.c_loc, t2.type,
       COALESCE(t.output, 0) output
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT o_date, c_loc FROM tablename) t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT type FROM tablename) t2
LEFT JOIN tablename t ON t.o_date = t1.o_date AND t.c_loc = t1.c_loc AND t.type = t2.type
ORDER BY t1.o_date, t1.c_loc, t2.type;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9f17857edf692967c4bb70b0a1420275).

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked well. Also, the demo was really helpful!

Comment: @rojin fine if it worked and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.